# Storing multiple strings to a single field in Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create a simple test program for a site. Basically the user will enter in a large amount of JSON. Then I will parse the JSON and get 10 random properties from the JSON. Then I will display those 10 properties and ask the user what the answer is. Then I am going to store the users answer in the admin panel as a way for me to check if they were right or wrong.

Basically I want to keep track of

```
property      user_answer      correct_answer
```

But I would like to keep it as a single item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using PostgreSQL you can store multiple strings in an [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/) and thus keep them as a single item like this:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models


class YourModel(models.Model):
    answers = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=255))
    # other fields for your model
```

If however, you are not using PostgreSQL as your database, you have to store the data in different fields like this:

```py
from django.db import models


class YourModel(models.Model):
    user_answer = models.CharField()
    correct_answer = models.CharField()
    # other fields for your model
```